# Controlled NOT gate with Control activated when input is 0 instead of 1

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

How I can implement this CNOT gate with control activated when input is 0 instead of 1 in Qiskit. Refer [circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22X%22%5D%5D%7D)

I'm adding 8 to the input with the CNOT and X gates. I want to set a flag when the sum adds up to 8. When the sum is 8, the 2nd and 3rd qubit outputs 0. In which case I want to apply the CNOT with control activated when input is 0 rather than 1.

I do not want to apply X gate before the controlled-gate to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNOT that controls on a 0 is usually called "open-controlled" and it can be implemented in Qiskit like this:

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.cx(0, 1, ctrl_state=0)
circuit.draw()
```

```
q_0: ──o──
     ┌─┴─┐
q_1: ┤ X ├
     └───┘
```

[Your circuit](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B1,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22%E2%97%A6%22,%22X%22%5D%5D%7D) requires a multi-open-controlled Toffoli, that is an instance of [MCXGate (multi controlled X gate)](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.MCXGate.html):

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import MCXGate

circuit = QuantumCircuit(4)
for _ in range(4):
    circuit.cx(1, 2)
    circuit.x(1)
circuit.append(MCXGate(3, ctrl_state="000"), [0, 1, 2, 3])
circuit.draw()
```

```
q_0: ──────────────────────────────────────────o──
          ┌───┐     ┌───┐     ┌───┐     ┌───┐  │  
q_1: ──■──┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├──■──┤ X ├──o──
     ┌─┴─┐└───┘┌─┴─┐└───┘┌─┴─┐└───┘┌─┴─┐└───┘  │  
q_2: ┤ X ├─────┤ X ├─────┤ X ├─────┤ X ├───────o──
     └───┘     └───┘     └───┘     └───┘     ┌─┴─┐
q_3: ────────────────────────────────────────┤ X ├
                                             └───┘
```

Answer (score 1):

In Qiskit, you can use the method [`Gate.control`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Gate.control.html) or [`ControlledGate.control`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.ControlledGate.control.html) to create a controlled version of any given `Gate` or `ControlledGate`, respectively.
This method takes an argument `num_ctrl_qubits` to specify the number of control qubits you want to add (`=3` in you case) and an argument `ctrl_state` which is a bitstring matching the number of controls and representing the control state (`='000'` in your case).

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import XGate

cccx = XGate().control(num_ctrl_qubits=3, ctrl_state='000')

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.append(cccx, range(4))

qc.draw('mpl')
```

[image]